# How to rollapply array along 3rd dimension?

Tags: r, zoo

Say that I have the array:

```
> arr <- array(1, dim=c(3, 3, 3))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

I'd like to calculate a moving average using a rolling window of size 2. Which means I want to calculate the moving average of each 3rd dimension of the array taking them 2 by 2. In the end, I would have something like:

```
> rollmeanThatWorksWithArrays(arr, k=2, margin=c(1, 2))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

I can do this mean along the 3rd dimension using `apply(arr, margin=c(1, 2), mean)`, but haven't figured out how to do a rolling mean. Maybe the rollmean/rollapply simply doesn't support it, and I'll have to write my own functions?

Comment: While the example data is appreciated, having a constant value example for a rolling mean is kind of pointless.

Comment: @thelatemail yeah, I know. I was trying to keep in as simple as possible, although it might make it a bit confusing. Bear with me and imagine that the arrays are filled with random data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty manually you could do this as follows (using different array than yours):

```
library(zoo)
arr <- array(1:27, dim=c(3, 3, 3))
res <- do.call(rbind ,tapply(c(arr), rep(1:9, 3), function(x) rollmean(x, k = 2)))
array(c(res), dim = c(3, 3, 2))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  5.5  8.5 11.5
[2,]  6.5  9.5 12.5
[3,]  7.5 10.5 13.5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 14.5 17.5 20.5
[2,] 15.5 18.5 21.5
[3,] 16.5 19.5 22.5
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll leave the question open for a few more days to see if someone thinks of a better solution, but yours look nice. I know it's unrelated to the original question, but is it possible to (easily) paralellize this? I'm working with a 644x644x432 array and it takes a while to run it using a single core.

Comment: I would change the second line to `do.call(rbind ,tapply(c(arr), rep(1:644, 432), function(x) rollmean(x, k = 2)))` and the last line to `array(c(res), dim = c(644, 644, 432-1))
`

Answer (score 1):

Assume input `arr` as in @RStudent's answer.  First create a data.frame `ix` of array indexes which define subsets of `arr` over which to take the mean. Define `Mean` to take the mean over a list of arrays.  Finally for each `ix` column `k` form `arr[,,k]` and turn it into a list suitable as input to `Mean`.  Take the `Mean` and simplify the result to an array.

```
library(zoo)

w <- 2 # width

arr <- array(1:27, c(3, 3, 3))
n <- dim(arr)[3]

ix <- as.data.frame(t(rollapply(1:n, w, c)))
Mean <- function(L) Reduce("+", L) / length(L)
simplify2array(lapply(ix, function(ix) Mean(lapply(ix, function(k) arr[,,k]))))
```

giving:

```
, , V1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  5.5  8.5 11.5
[2,]  6.5  9.5 12.5
[3,]  7.5 10.5 13.5

, , V2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 14.5 17.5 20.5
[2,] 15.5 18.5 21.5
[3,] 16.5 19.5 22.5
```